# How do I get my selected all data in input one value?

Tags: php, input, explode

I am selecting many rows through the check box. and Took multiple rows at one value.
Let's say
'id' ROW contains three such as 12,14,16. In this case `$id` shows the latest data "16" when it is echoed out.
How do I get my selected data?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo"
       value="<?php echo $row['id'].','.$row['name']; ?>">

<?php
  $myvar= explode(',', $_POST['foo']);
  $id = $myvar[0];
  $name = $myvar[1];
?>
```

Comment: Please show us more code.

Comment: You probably need to name your form field `foo[]` to make it into an array, but it's difficult to tell without a bit more detail. If you give all the checkboxes the same scalar name, you're only going to see the last one submitted as each will overwrite the previous one when parsed into `$_POST`, surely?